# How to make links in Search bar go to a different page?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a somewhat working search bar and it works the way I want it, I was just wondering if it was possible to add links to different items Searched? Right now anything Searched redirect's to 'Session.php' Am I able to for example if someone search for 'Home' am I able to display results and then the user is able to click 'Home.php'? Thanks!

Search.php Code:

```
<?php 
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
session_start();
//checks if the login session is true
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---
 ?> 

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css">
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("aha") or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
</html>
```

Logout

```
    <head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 3;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles
            WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what I'm looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

       if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop



echo "<a href='../pages/session.php'><h3>{$results['title']}</h3></a><p>{$results['text']}</‌​p>";



    }


}
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    echo ("<br><br>No results</br></br>");
}

}

else{ // if query length is less than minimum
echo ("</br></br>Minimum length  is</br></br> ".$min_length);
}

?>


</body>

<br>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-search" type="button" href="index.php" >Search Again</a>
</br>
</br>




 DB FOR ARTICLE:
```

http://puu.sh/ctUUq/2f73509cf2.png

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean showing recent searches?

Comment: @devaldcool Like, lets say a user searches for 'Home' I wanted it to be display 'Home' and redirect to 'Home.php'. So on and so forth

Comment: In a dropdown (like google does) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the page name for each record in your database, and then retrieve it with your query.

Considering you'd store it in a column named "page_name" on your SQL table, change this line to point to the right page, according to user's query :

```
echo "<a href='../pages/{$results['page_name']}'><h3>{$results['title']}</h3></a><p>{$results['text']}</‌​p>";
```

Comment: ['page_name']}.php What do I put in there :(?

Comment: @Sarah For each line of your database, you have to store the name of your .php file (for instance, 'Home.php'). I edited the answer a bit, you'd better include the file extension in your SQL field

Comment: Thanks for the hand, I've figured it out but I am getting this error Notice: Undefined index: page_name in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd6_osmanovic\pages\search.php on line 74

Comment: @Sarah You have to add a column named "page_name" in SQL ;) And fill the blank (add a value on this field for your existing rows)

Comment: Again thanks for the massive help! Just one more question, why is it when I remove the word 'Session' from the 'text' column the 'title' and link both dissapear? Thanks :)!

Comment: @Sarah I guess because your query is "Session", so you do not have any match? The value of `$_GET['query']` can be seen in your url, check if you have `?query=session`

Comment: @Sarah You may find it in your URL, not your code. It was just a guess by the way :) Anyway, is your initial problem solved?